# Calendar dont work as expected

Tags: java, android

I am using the Calendar API but I think I do it wrong

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 19);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    Log.d("TAG", cal.getTime().toString());
```

Why do I get this value?

```
D/TAG﹕ Thu Jan 09 13:24:24 CEST 4031
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can you tell us what's your purpose ?

Comment: Better to use joda-time.

Comment: Have you tried to get the value of `new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());` think then you have the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `add`, you are effectively getting a calendar instance that is 2015 years, 6 months, 20 days, and 19 hours *later* than now. Instead use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar-int-int-int-int-int-):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 5, 20, 19, 0);
```

and do not call `add`.

Alternatively, you can use `set` instead of add:

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);  // 0-based
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `add`, not `set`, so you are adding `2015` years, `6` months, etc. to a `Calendar` object that is already initialized to now (June 19, 2015).

Call `set` instead.  Don't forget to subtract one from the months, which are `0` based, or you'll get July instead of June.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);  // 5 is June because 0 is January
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

Comment: To set a month it's better to use constants from `Callendar` class instead of simple numbers, e.g. `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Callendar.JUNE)` instead of `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5)`. That way you will never have to remember to substract one.